# Select $x(t)$ such that it minimizes $J$, $J = \int_0^T \left[(x - e^{-t})^2 + (\dot{x} + 1)^2\right]dt$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I am given two situations, $A$ and $B$.

For $A$, the ideal $x(t)$ is $e^{-t}$ for $0 \le t \le T$.

However, for $B$, the ideal $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is $-1$ for $0 \le t \le T$.

I am to make a compromise and select $x(t)$ such that it minimizes $J$,

$$J = \int_0^T \left[(x - e^{-t})^2 + (\dot{x} + 1)^2\right]dt$$

I am asked to find a differential equation that the optimal $x(t)$, $x^*(t)$, must satisfy and solve for this $x^*(t)$ under the conditions that $T=1$, $x(0) =1$, and $x(1) = 0.5$.

What I'm trying to solve: $x''-x=-e^{-t}$.

Solution should look like: $x(t) = c_1e^{\lambda_1t} + c_2e^{\lambda_2t} + x(p)$, where $x(p)$ is a particular solution.

Let $x(p) = Ate^{-t}$.

Then $x'(p) = Ae^{-t} - Ate^{-t}$ and $x''(p) = -2Ae^{-t} +Ate^{-t}$.

Substituting into $x''-x=-e^{-t}$ gives $-2Ae^{-t} + Ate^{-t} - Ate^{-t} = -e^{-t}$.

$\implies A = \frac{1}{2} \implies x(p) = \frac{1}{2}te^{-t}$.

Using the boundary conditions:

$x(0) = 1 \implies c_1 + c_2 = 1$ and $x(1) = \frac{1}{2} \implies c_1e + \frac{c_2}{e} + \frac{1}{2e} = \frac{1}{2}$

[According to Wolphram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%20%2B%20b%20%3D%201%20and%20ae%20%2B%20b%2Fe%20%2B%201%2F2e%20%3D%201%2F2), the values for my $c_i$ are messy.

Comment: Are you asking about the Euler Lagrange equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations you need to derive are known as Euler-Lagrange equations; assume $x(t)$ minimizes the action.  Then any sufficiently small perturbation $x(t) + \delta \phi(t)$ (with a smooth test function $\phi$) will give a larger value to the action.  Let $I$ be the action evaluated at $x(t)$ and $I_\delta$ the same action evaluated at $x(t)+\delta\phi(t)$.  If you take the limit of the ratio $|I_\delta-I|/\delta$ as $\delta\to 0$ you should get zero by the variational principle.  After some manipulation and with the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations you will get the Euler-Lagrange equation.  I will not give details since the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equations is contained in every book of Calculus of Variations.

Your Lagrangian is $L(t,x,v)=(x-e^{-t})^2+(v+1)^2$ so $L_x = 2(x-e^{-t})$ and $L_{v} = 2(v+1)$ giving you $$2(x-e^{-t})=2\ddot{x},$$ a linear second order non-homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients.  In more usual form, $$x''-x=-e^{-t}.$$  Do you know how to solve equations like this?

Comment: Find the solution to the corresponding homogenous ODE, then add the particular solution to that result?

Comment: Yes, this is what you need to do to complete the problem.  Find the general solution to the homogeneous ODE.  Then see if you can find a particular solution to the non-homogeneous one.  If not, ask and I will give you a hint.

Comment: My general solution should be $x(t) = c_1e^{\lambda_1 t}+c_2e^{\lambda_2 t}$, where $\lambda_1 = -1$ and $\lambda_2 = 1$. I then used $x(0)=1$ to get $c_1 +c_2 = 1$ and $x(1) = 0.5$ to get $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{c_1}{e} +c_2e$.

Comment: This is the general solution of the homogeneous equation.  You cannot use that with the given initial values.  You need to add a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation into the mix.  You need to have $x(t)=c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}+x_p(t)$ and you still have not found $x_p(t)$.  Once you have, and only then, can you plug in zeros to solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Is $x_p(t) = -te^{-t}$?

Comment: Close, but you got the coefficient wrong.  It should be $x_p(t) = \frac{1}{2}te^{-t}$.  So now you have $x(t) = c_1e^t +c_2e^{-t}+\frac{1}{2}te^{-t}$ and you can plug in your values to get $c_1$ and $c_2$.  Note how the presence of $x_p(t)$ makes a difference in $x(1)$ from your previous computation.  After you find the $c_i$ you will be done.

Comment: Letting $c_1 = a$ and $c_2 = b$ I get these values: [Wolphram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%2B+b+%3D+1+and+ae+%2B+b%2Fe+%2B+1%2F2e+%3D+1%2F2)

Comment: Those values seem particularly messy. I'm assuming I made another mistake?

Comment: I see in your revised question you took $x_p(t)$ as $\frac{-1}{2}te^{-t}$ although the value you found was $A=1/2$, not $A=-1/2$.  Be careful.

Comment: I see. However, I still get ugly values for my $c_i$.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with those values.