# Does $x^*(t) =(\frac{2 - e + e^2}{2 - 2e^2})e^t + (\frac{e - 3e^2}{2 - 2e^2})e^{-t} + \frac{1}{2}te^{-t}$ contain corner points?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I want to know if $x^*(t) =(\frac{2 - e + e^2}{2 - 2e^2})e^t + (\frac{e - 3e^2}{2 - 2e^2})e^{-t} + \frac{1}{2}te^{-t}$ can contain corner points.

This $x^*(t)$ is the solution to the differential equation $x'' - x = -e^{-t}$, which was the solution to [This Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014542/select-xt-such-that-it-minimizes-j-j-int-0t-leftx-e-t2/1014563?noredirect=1#comment2073916_1014563).

I believe, though I'm not sure, that I must use the Erdmann-Weierstrass corner conditions:

$$(i) f_{\dot{x}}|_{t = t_{c^-}} = f_{\dot{x}}|_{t = t_{c^+}}$$

$$(ii) [f - \dot{x}f_{\dot{x}}]_{t = t_{c^-}} = [f - \dot{x}f_{\dot{x}}]_{t = t_{c^+}}$$

For $(i)$, using my value for $f_{\dot{x}}$ that I obtained from the link I provided, I got the following:

$$2(\dot{x}(t) + 1)|_{t = t_{c^-}} = 2(\dot{x}(t) + 1)|_{t = t_{c^+}}$$

$$\dot{x}(t_{c^-}) = \dot{x}(t_{c^+})$$

$$\dot{x}(t_{c^-}) - \dot{x}(t_{c^+}) = 0$$

At this point, I'm thinking that there cannot be any corner points, but I am a bit confused about how to apply the corner conditions and whether those corner conditions are even what I need to show if $\dot{x}(t)$ can have corner points.

Answer (score 1):

$x^*(t)$ doesn't contain any corner, since $x^*(t)$ is continuously differentiable, because each term of it has this property.